# Передать параметры анимации в функцию jQuery

Tags: jquery, анимация, javascript, функции

Добрый день, вопрос такой.

Я пишу функцию анимирующую блок, ей параметром передается скорость. По умолчанию анимация следующая:

```
animate({opacity: 'show', height: 'show'}, parseInt(settings.speed))
```

Как правильно обеспечить возможность выбрать анимацию только slide или только fade через параметры?

Answer (score 3):

```
function yourAnimFunc(settings){
    $('selector')[settings.animType](parseInt(settings.speed));
}
```

а в вашу функцию передавайте:

```
yourAnimFunc({animType: 'fadeIn', speed: '1000'});
```